# Cubos de alguns clientes no Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence

Pretendo permitir que meus clientes acessem seus dados para gerar relatórios customizados e utilizar o poder do PowerPivot do Excel.
Hoje todos os clientes (business) estão na mesma base de dados e pelo pouco que sei sobre cubos desenhei a seguinte estratégia.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os cubos podem ficar em outros servidores (Azure, Amazon, servidor físico dedicado,...). O importante é que eles serão gerados a partir da uma base dados principal (com todos os dados).

Minhas perguntas:

1. Eu consigo trabalhar desta forma?
2. Como eu crio um cubo restringindo pelo id_bus? Estou utilizando o SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008.
3. Eu consigo criar um usuário que tenha acesso de leitura somente a um cubo específico?

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver minha demanda utilizando o SSIS (Integration Services) com Visual Studio.

- Eu crio as bases (Basic) Azure SQL com as tabelas que quero publicar para meu cliente
- No SSIS eu criei um pacote (package) para cada cliente com a conexão de origem e destino dos dados. Também criei uma variável que é o identificador do cliente na qual os filtros vão considerar.
- Publiquei o projeto no Integration Services Catalog do banco de dados e programei um JOB para  executar os packages toda a madrugada.
- Para meu cliente eu disponibilizo as credenciais de acesso ao banco Azure (usuário somente de leitura) na qual ele utilizará no PowerPivot do Excel.

Segue o link de um bom tutorial de SSIS. Vale a pena dar uma explorada para quem demandas parecidas ou tem algum trabalho periódico na extração/migração/transformação de dados. Dá até para gerar planilhas Excel com os dados.

[Tutorial SSIS com Azure SQL](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/84/posts/13234/how-to-use-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-to-migrate-data-from-sql-server-to-sql-azure-paras-d.aspx)